# How to add a hidden image to a PDF document?

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

I have a program. It outputs to pdf, but that is close to impossible to read from again. So i need a additional file attached to my PDF in order to be able to make it editable in my program. Attaching a file to PDF is a good idea, but that is visible to the user, which i don't wan't it to be.

An alternative is to hide my readable file format inside an image which would be added to the PDF somewhere to the top of the first page, before everything else... Even to metadata if that's possible...

That way I can extract image from pdf using a PDF library (iText), and read from it.

My question is how to add image to PDF to be as well hidden as it could be (visually and by accesibility). And it has to be in a place which would be same for any created document (somewhere on the top, or on the very bottom of the document, or to the part of the document which isn't displayed at all... I'm really guessing here, I'm not really familliar with PDF file format)...

Any ideas?

P.S. It's not really important which image is it, I could be a e.g. completly transparent image, 1x1 pixels.

Comment: I want to simply stick a picture on PDF somewhere user will not see it or be able to access it. Picture can have any desired attributes that would help hide it (e.g. transparency, small size, etc.).

Comment: "i need a additional file attached to my PDF in order to be able to make it editable in my program." - it's not really clear why having a file attaached to your PDF would make it editable by your program. Are you trying to do some kind of watermark?

Comment: I'm attaching a file which will contain the PDF contents in a way that will be readable to my program.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by Image, but you can "extend" the PDF reference.

A PDF consists of objects: PDF numbers, PDF names, PDF strings, PDF arrays, PDF dictionaries, PDF streams. What you probably want, is to add an entry to a dictionary (pick one: the root dictionary, the info dictionary, the root of the page tree,...) that isn't defined in the PDF reference, so that it isn't rendered in a PDF viewer.

The key of such an entry must be a PDF name. To avoid clashes with existing names (names that are part of a current PDF spec, or will be part of a future spec), it is advised to register a four-letter key with ISO. For instance, Adobe registered adbe, iText registered ITXT and use that name with an underscore. For instance, ITXT_OriginalData would be a good name if we needed the functionality you describe.

The value of such an entry will be a PDF stream. In iText, you need the PdfStream class for this.